# Create a grid using user input number of rows and columns

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and I m trying to create a matrix with editText in its cell which should have user input number of rows and columns. The user should input the numbers in one activity and the matrix should form in another activity. Please help me with this!

Comment: Learn gridview from google thats easy,  gridview will show items like list one after another,  you have to just set how many column you want to grid show. Hope this get you started

Comment: if i set the number of columns then everytime the program runs it will have same number of columns. but i want user to set the number of columns and grid should be automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

Pass number of rows and column to next activity and programmatically set number of columns and rows to your grid

Comment: yeah that is the same what i thought. But i want to know how to programmatically set the number of rows and columns to the grid?And each cell of the grid should have editText so that user can input the numbers.

Comment: @lavmhrzn use CUSTOMVIEW and adapter for gridview and for passing data to activity use intent.putExtra() and getextra()

Comment: Set number of columns programmatically

gridView.setNumColumns(columnNumber);

it will take number rows required automatically

and then use custom adapter

Comment: The best solution is to use RecyclerView with grid layout and set max column programmatically , by using recyclerAdapter you can do whatever you wanted to do with your row items